# change preg_replace to preg_replace_callback not work

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

i have php code :

```
preg_replace('#<!-- '.(($c)?'\#':'').'BEGIN '.$block.' -->[\r\n]*(.*?)[\r\n]*<!-- '.(($c)?'\#':'').'END '.$block.' -->#se',
            '$s = stripslashes("\\1");',$str);
```

now i change to :

```
preg_replace_callback('#<!-- '.(($c)?'\#':'').'BEGIN '.$block.' -->[\r\n]*(.*?)[\r\n]*<!-- '.(($c)?'\#':'').'END '.$block.' -->#s',
                function($m){
                return $s = stripslashes($m[1]);},
                $str);
```

but not working too, and not show error

Help me, Thanks!

This my function to load html file

```
var $ext = ".html";
var $cache_temp = array();
function get_htm($filename,$blockname = '',$c = false) {
    $full_link = $_SESSION['skin_folder']."/".$filename.$this->ext;
    if (!file_exists($full_link)) {
        die("Không tìm thấy file : <b>".$full_link."</b>");
    }
    if ($this->cache_temp['file_'.$filename]) $file_content = $this->cache_temp['file_'.$filename];
    else {
        $this->cache_temp['file_'.$filename] = $file_content = file_get_contents($full_link);
    }
    return $file_content;
}

function get_block_from_htm($str,$block = '',$c = false) {

    if (!$this->cache_temp['block_'.$block]) {
        preg_replace('#<!-- '.(($c)?'\#':'').'BEGIN '.$block.' -->[\r\n]*(.*?)[\r\n]*<!-- '.(($c)?'\#':'').'END '.$block.' -->#se','$s = stripslashes("\1");',$str);
        if ($s != $str) $str = $s;
        else $str = '';
        $this->cache_temp['block_'.$block] = $str;
    }
    return $this->cache_temp['block_'.$block];
}
```

and html file look like this

```html
bot.html
<div class="bloc01 bgd01">
<h2>Bot online now</h2>
<ul class="list01">
<!-- BEGIN bot --> 
<!-- #BEGIN bot.row --><div class="tr03"><li>  
abc123
</li></div>
<!-- #END bot.row --> 
<!-- END bot -->
</ul>
</div>
...
last_search.html
<div class="bloc01 bgd01">
<h2>last_search</h2>
<ul class="list01">
<li>
<!-- BEGIN last_search --> 
<!-- #BEGIN last_search.row --> <div class="tr03"><li> 
def456
</li></div>
<!-- #END last_search.row --> 
<!-- END last_search -->
</li>
</ul>
</div>
...
```

when i chang to php7 i need to update my code But affter i change code from preg_replace to preg_replace_callback my code not work anh not show error

Comment: What is `$str`, `$c`, and `$block`?

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: @chris85 i have update my Question, Thank you!

Comment: @Rizier123 affter my update code, my page not show anything.

Comment: @ĐỗViếtNam: Check [this demo](https://3v4l.org/hQBVN).